# Is it possible to have multiple onContextItemSelected in same activity

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

With the help of [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177074/is-it-possible-to-have-2-context-menus-in-same-activity) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315269/android-trouble-with-using-multiple-context-menus), I created a ContextMenu for my two listviews like this

```
    final int DELETE = 0;
    final int CANCEL = 1;
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.history_listView:
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Delete History?");
        menu.add(0, DELETE, 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, CANCEL, 0, "Cancel");
        break;

    case R.id.bookmark_listView:
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Delete Bookmark?");
        menu.add(0, DELETE, 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, CANCEL, 0, "Cancel");
    }
}
```

Now I want to have two onContextItemSelected methods, one for history  and another for bookmarks. I have created one for history, which is working fine.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case DELETE:
        String deleteSelectedHistory = (String) historyData.get(info.position);
        historyData.remove(info.position);
        historyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        break;

    case CANCEL:
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But am unable to create another for bookmarks. Is it possible to have another onContextItemSelected method in same activity? Or is there a way to create a second one?

Comment: Just declare different IDs for history and bookmarks.e.g. HIS_DELETE,HIS_CANCEL, BM_DELETE,BM_CANCEL.

Comment: @HirenDabhi So how do I check which delete was pressed, in onContextItemSeleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code. it may help you.

```
final int HIS_DELETE = 0;
final int HIS_CANCEL = 1;
final int BM_DELETE = 2;
final int BM_CANCEL = 3;

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.history_listView:
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Delete History?");
        menu.add(0, HIS_DELETE, 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, HIS_CANCEL, 0, "Cancel");
        break;

    case R.id.bookmark_listView:
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Delete Bookmark?");
        menu.add(0, BM_DELETE, 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, BM_CANCEL, 0, "Cancel");
    }
}
```

and onContextItemSelected method like,

```
    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case HIS_DELETE:
        Log.d("System out", "HIS_DELETE");
        break;
    case HIS_CANCEL:
        Log.d("System out", "HIS_CANCEL");
        break;
    case BM_DELETE:
        Log.d("System out", "BM_DELETE");
        break;
    case BM_CANCEL:
        Log.d("System out", "BM_CANCEL");
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am stumbling across this as I feel a stroke of luck. Any reason why it does not have more upvotes? After 5 years of further development, do you still find this best practice?